# Return control from thread to scheduler (context switching)

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a simple threading library using context switching for a college project. I am having troubles returning from the thread execution.

Originally I switched to a newly created thread like this:

```
  int done = 0;
  getcontext(&parent_context);                                          
  if (!done) {
    done = 1;
    setcontext(&(thread->context));
  }
  return thread->tid;
```

Where `thread->context.uc_link` is `&parent_context`. It works, but I need to call a scheduler upon thread creation instead of just switching to its context. So I set `thread->context.uc_link` to `NULL` instead of `&parent_context` and replaced the above code with

```
schedule(thread);
scheduler();
return thread->tid;
```

Where `schedule` enqueues the thread and `scheduler` gets the first thread in the queue and calls `dispatcher`, which is just a call to `setcontext`. The thing is, I need the thread to return control to the scheduler. The first thing that occurred me was doing:

```
static void
scheduler()
{
  int dispatched = 0;
  ucontext_t ret;
  // Get the first thread in the queue, then
  thread->context.uc_link = &ret;
  getcontext(&ret);
  if (!dispatched) {
    dispatched = 1;
    setcontext(&(thread->context));
  }
  // Remove the dispatched thread from the queue
}
```

Which is not working - the thread doesn't return control to the scheduler and the program finishes after the thread terminates its execution. I assume this is because I didn't call `makecontext` after changing `uc_link`. However, in order to call `makecontext` I would have to pass to the scheduler the thread's function pointer and arguments, which is not desirable, as I cannot modify the thread data structure to store that (project rules). The threading "libraries" using context switching I found online do a `setcontext` call inside the thread's function:

http://www.evanjones.ca/software/threading.html

http://nitish712.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/thread-library-using-context-switching.html

This is not desirable either, as the user should not need to do the context switching himself. How can I make the thread return control to the scheduler? One hack I can think of is using a static variable `ucontext_t return_context` and using it as all thread's `uc_link`. So before I call the scheduler I do `getcontext(&return_context)` and the scheduler becomes:

```
  // Get the first thread in the queue, then
  // Remove the thread from the queue
  setcontext(&(thread->context));
```

This seems to work, but this way no two threads can execute at the same time. It is not an issue for this project, but it seems wrong. Another issue is that every function calling the scheduler acts sort of as a dispatcher:

```
int done = 0;
getcontext(&return_context);
if (!done) {
  done = 1;
  scheduler();
}
fprintf(stderr, "Thread returned\n");
```

Is this the way to go?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to implement parallel threads in user-space. The evanjones.ca link mentions fibers, which are usually cooperatively-asynchronous and not parallel.

Comment: The starting premise that you are implementing threading via context *switching* implies that you will be performing CPU slicing, not concurrent multithreading.  Two threads do not require context switching to run concurrently on different cores.

Comment: Nevertheless, your library could perhaps be made to operate in the context of multiple parallel OS threads.  I don't think you would be able to transfer contexts between threads, but if you are careful to avoid global data then you could perform slicing within a thread.  Where you otherwise might want a global, consider thread-local data instead.

Answer (score 0):

What the code needs to do depends on the environment where the code is running.

If running under a OS like Linux or MAC or Windows,  the user does not really have much control.

If running on a 'barebones' platform, The the choice needs to be made:

pre-emptive context switching or permissive context switching.

In pre-emptive context switching, a interrupt handler triggers the scheduler (which will trigger the dispatcher which will actually cause a 'thread' to resume execution) and the scheduler saves the current context, decides what to run next (which will depend on how long since the thread was run and priority of the available contexts and whither the specific context is 'blocked' as in waiting for  some event.

In permissive context switching, the thread calls the scheduler, thereby giving up the CPU to to the scheduler, which will resume which ever thread is not blocked & highest priority & been delayed the longest.

The scheduler, in a time sensitive system, will also check that a thread that needs to be run periodically has completed its' prior execution before re-starting that thread.  If the thread has not completed its' prior execution, then a error is asserted, with usually involves logging the error and re-starting the system.

So, just what environment is your code expected to run in?